# How do I call a C# method using JavaScript in .NET Framework 4.7.2?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net

Whenever the textbox value changes a C# method should be called. The textbox uses a calendar validator so when a user changes the date it should count as a value change. The date can be changed by clicking on a new date or typing it in. Typing it in can possibly call the method multiple times which is fine. **How can I activate a C# method whenever a textbox value is changed using JavaScript in .NET Framework 4.7.2?**

**.ascx file:**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#textBox1).change(function () {
            // How can I call the buttonClick method?
        }
    });
 </script>

<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="date" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textBox1"
    ErrorMessage="Date Required" CssClass="field-validation-error"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<ajax:CalendarExtender ID="ceDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="textBox1"  />
```

**.ascx.cs file:**

```
protected void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //...
    }
```

I tried doing this without JavaScript. There is an OnTextChanged event listener that should call the buttonClick method. This has not been working for me. Clicking on a new date or typing in the textbox doesn't trigger the method. It only seems to trigger when I press the 'Enter' key. The event listener should not depend on the 'Enter' key being pressed.

**.ascx file:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="buttonClick"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="date" runat="server" ControlToValidate="textBox1"
    ErrorMessage="Required" CssClass="field-validation-error"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<ajax:CalendarExtender ID="ceDate" runat="server" TargetControlID="textBox1"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#textBox1").change(function () {
        <%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(textBox1, "") %>
    }
  });
</script>
```

But take care that under certain circumstances, the `id` value of the text box control will not necessarily be the same as the ID (name) of the textbox control on the server side. One way to make sure that your jQuery selector uses the correct value for the `id` of the textbox control is to use the `ClientID` property of the server-side object, like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#<%= textBox1.ClientID %>").change(function () {
        <%= Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(textBox1, "") %>
    }
  });
</script>
```

Or if you don't want to bother with using the `ClientID` property, then you can set the value of `ClientIDMode` attribute on the mark-up of the control to `Static`, then the `id` on the server and client will always be the same, like so:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="buttonClick" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

However, it is not advisable to use `ClientIDMode="Static"` within custom user controls, since you could end up with multiple elements with the same ID on the client when the control is used multiple times on the same page.

**Method 2:**

It is also possible to achieve all this without using JavaScript.

The `buttonClick` server-side event handler will **not** be called until the form is posted back to the server-side.

One way to automatically do a post-back to the server whenever the text is changed is by adding the `AutoPostBack="true"` attribute to the mark-up of the `textBox1` control:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" OnTextChanged="buttonClick" AutoPostBack="true"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Side-note**: Remember, doing a post-back will cause the whole page/control life-cycle to be executed, even if your controls are within an `<asp:UpdatePanel>...</asp:UpdatePanel>` block (for asynchronous/ajax updates), so things like the `Page_Load` function will be run every time there is a post-back. If you have initialization code within such functions and you don't want to re-initialize on every post-back, just check that the Request is **not** post-back before running initialization code, i.e:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        // initialization
    }
}
```